# How to put two mean plots on a single plane with different scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I obtained the two separate mean plots. Is there any simple way to combine them on a single plane with different line colours? Tricky part is each has a different scale, so I want to put one (`lshare`) scale on left hand side of y-axis and the other (`va`) on right side of y-axis.

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = lshare)) + stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = mean) 

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = va)) + stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = mean)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: See `facet_wrap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update2**:
Combining all:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, disp) %>% 
  mutate(year = 1900:1931) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    c(mpg, disp)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=value, group=name, color=name))+
  stat_summary(fun =mean, geom="line", size=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "my first y axis",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~./10, name="my second y axis")
  )
```

[image]

**Update:** How to add secodn y axis as requested:
[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, disp) %>% 
  mutate(year = 1900:1931) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year))+
  geom_line(aes(y=mpg*10), size=1, color="red")+
  geom_line(aes(y=disp), size=1, color="blue") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "my first y axis",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~./10, name="my second y axis")
  )
```

**First answer:**
Here is a reproducible example with the `mtcars` dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, disp) %>% 
  mutate(year = 1900:1931) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    c(mpg, disp)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=value, group=name, color=name))+
  stat_summary(fun =mean, geom="line", size=1)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the part of the OP's question on the two different y-axes.

Comment: The original question was: "I obtained the two separate mean plots. Is there any simple way to combine them on a single plane with different line colours?" But anyway thank you for pointing out. I will update.

Comment: Please see my update. Many thanks.

Comment: @TarJae thanks, so do I have only to add  `scale_y_continuous(
    name = my first y axis,
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~./10, name="my second y axis")` to the second chunk? Could you combine the 1st and 2nd chunk for a complete update?

Comment: Yes exactly . Please see my update.

Comment: @TarJae, sorry for some reason, I got `Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Can't convert from <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision.`

Comment: No problem. Do we have your data somewhere. Could you share or it is not possible?

Comment: @Joe, both the approaches of TarJae and me work fine. You could also try ‘addition 2’ of my solution on your own data. Just play a bit with the equation in the sec_axis() function. Cheers!

Comment: I got it. many thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

As @jdobres commented, you can use `facet_wrap()`, like in the following example. Simply introduce a grouping factor to your `data.frame`.

```
set.seed(1)

# sample data
year <- 1:20
lshare <- 0.50 - 0.02 * year + rnorm(length(year), sd = 3)
df <- data.frame(year = c(year, year), lshare = c(lshare, lshare))
df$group <- factor(gl(2, length(year)))

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = lshare, colour = group)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = mean, size = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~ group)
```

[image]

**Addition**

As per your edit, which I saw after I posted this answer, `facet_wrap()` also works when you want to have two different y-axes. You just have to play a bit with the function that is specified within `sec_axis()`.

```
set.seed(1)

# sample data
year <- 1:20
lshare <- 0.50 - 0.02 * year + rnorm(length(year), sd = 3)
noise <- abs(rnorm(length(lshare), mean = 150, sd = 100))
df <- data.frame(year = c(year, year), lshare = c(lshare, lshare + noise))
df$group <- factor(gl(2, length(year)))

# set two limits
ylim_left <- with(subset(df, group == 1), c(min(lshare), max(lshare)))
ylim_right <- with(subset(df, group == 2), c(min(lshare), max(lshare)))

axis_right <- diff(ylim_left)/diff(ylim_right)
axis_left <- ylim_left[1] - axis_right * ylim_right[1]

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = lshare, colour = group)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = mean, size = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~ group) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - axis_left)/axis_right))
```

[image]

**Addition 2**

If you would like to have the two lines in the same pane, you can use something along the following lines of code. Note, I use the same data as in the first addition (see above).

```
# set two limits
ylim_left <- with(subset(df, group == 1), c(min(lshare), max(lshare)))
ylim_right <- with(subset(df, group == 2), c(min(lshare), max(lshare)))

axis_right <- diff(ylim_left)/diff(ylim_right)
axis_left <- ylim_left[1] - axis_right * ylim_right[1]

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(colour = group)) +
  stat_summary(data = subset(df, group == 1),
               mapping = aes(x = year, y = lshare),
               geom = "line", fun = mean, size = 1) +
  stat_summary(data = subset(df, group == 2),
               mapping = aes(x = year, y = lshare),
               geom = "line", fun = mean, size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - axis_left)/axis_right)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'My_groups',
                      values = c('1' = "blue4", '2' = "darkorange"),
                      labels = c('Group 1', 'Group 2'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but Maybe my post is written confusing way. I want to put two lines on a single plane.

Comment: Ah, I see. I will adapt the answer accordingly.